# jQuery: unbind dblclick and then bind it again

Tags: jquery, bind, unbind

I have a table with different database query results. Each td has an id and an onDblClick property like this:

```
<td id="Vorname_2036" onDblClick="makeForm(this.id)">
    Mark
</td>
```

Don't mind the name of the function, it does not really make a form. Instead it changes the inner HTML of the td to an editable text input, and onChange sends an AJAX request to a script that updates the database with the changed value of the text input. All of this is working as it should. 
The only thing is: After the first double click I want to disable dblclick, so the user won't double click into the text input. I managed to do this as well. But after everything is done I want to restore the onDblClick property. And this is where I am stuck.

Here is the code (The part that is commented out is the part that obviously is wrong):

```
function makeForm(id){
    $("#"+id).prop('ondblclick', "");
    sHtml=$("#"+id).html();
    $("#"+id).html("<input type=\"text\" id=\"t_"+id+"\" value=\""+sHtml+"\">");
    $("#"+id).change(function(){
        var content = $("#t_"+id).val();
        $("#"+id).html("<img src=\"icons/spinner.gif\" align=\"right\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\">");
        $.get("includes/query_update.php",{
            id:id,
            content:content
        },
        function(data){
            $("#"+id).html(data);
/*
            $("#"+id).dblclick(
                function(){
                    makeForm(this.id);
                }
            );
*/
        });
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Martin

Comment: The most common way to unbind an even in JQuery is usually to is `off()`. In your case it would be `$("#"+id).off("dblclick");`. I don't know if that would fix your issue, but I'd give it a try if I were you.

Comment: Thanks, that's ok, but my problem is how to get it back on again.

Comment: I know, what I'm saying is maybe the way you inbound it might be causing problems when rebinding it.

Comment: Thing is, when I uncomment the outcommented part, the  thing actually works, but when I try to change the content of the field the next time, it seems that the function calls itself several times. With every repeat the loop gets longer.

Comment: Have you tried changing the unbinding method? Cause what you describe here would look like the event is still bound when you are rebinding it (basically, each time you click the button, you binding the function to the same event). In JQuery, if you bind an event multiple times, it will get executed multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the unbinding method? Because what you described in the comments would look like the event is still bound when you are rebinding it (basically, each time you click the button, you binding the function to the same event). In JQuery, if you bind an event multiple times, it will get executed multiple times. My feel is that the way you are unbinding it is not right. The way you are doing it now you are removing the value of the propertie `OnDblClick` on the DOM (that actual HTML), while I guess you bound the even via the JQuery method `$('#id').dblClick(function() {})`. When bound the JQuery way, nothing is added in DOM (all is saved in memory in the JQuery code), which makes your unbinding effectively do nothing. Instead of unbinding the event the way you did, you should try unbinding it like this :

```
$("#"+id).off("dblclick");
```

which is the JQuery way.

Comment: Using off("dblclick") doesn't make a difference. The function still gets called more than once. I think it's the way I am trying to bind it back again.

Comment: 1 thing you could try to see if that's actually the case is to put an alert box (temporarily) in the `makeForm` function and see if it shows up multiple times.

Comment: That's what I did and that's what it does.

Comment: That's weird... I just looked at the JQuery doc again and this should work. The only things I could see now is either that your `function(data)` from the get gets called multiple times (which I don't why it could be happening), or that you might be attaching the event somewhere else.

Comment: HEY, I just realized (re-read your answer) that you also attached the event through the HTML. Shouldn't change anything though, cause I think JQuery will remove both handlers. However, one thing I just thought : When you double click multiple times, does the event get fired more and more times, or always 2 times (e.g. if you double click once, the event gets fired once, then you double click again, now it gets fired twice, then if you double click 3 times, does the event get fired 3 times as well, or only 2?)

Comment: Exactly, if I double click three times it fires three times.

Comment: I changed it so I add the dblclick event through jQuery instead of HTML.

Doesn't make a difference.

Comment: My original feeling remains in that it would seem the way you are unbinding the event doesn't seem to work, but I can't for the life of me figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is what I came up with myself. But I admit, it was just guesswork and I don't fully understand why it is working and probably it is terribly wrong. But it allows me to update the data in the table cell as often as I want without getting into a loop. Here it comes:

```
function makeForm(id){
    $("#"+id).prop('ondblclick', ""); // In the first round this disables the doubleclick event added through HTML (I think)
    $("#"+id).off("dblclick"); // In the second round this disables the doubleclick event added through jQuery (I think)
    sHtml=$("#"+id).html();
    $("#"+id).html("<input type=\"text\" id=\"t_"+id+"\" value=\""+sHtml+"\">");
    $("#"+id).change(function(){
        var content = $("#t_"+id).val();
        $("#"+id).html("<img src=\"icons/spinner.gif\" align=\"right\" width=\"20\" height=\"20\">");
        $.get("includes/query_update.php",{
            id:id,
            content:content
        },
        function(data){
            $("#"+id).html(data);
            $("#"+id).off("dblclick"); // This is beyond me. Why once more? Why here?
            $("#"+id).dblclick(
                function(){
                    makeForm(this.id);
                }
            );
        });
    });
}
```

If someone can improve this and explain to me what is really happening I will be terribly grateful.

Comment: Ok, the first bad idea was to attach the event handler through HTML.

Answer (score 0):

$(selector).unbind('dblclick')

Comment: For a useful answer this reaction needs to be extended. Explain why this is an answer to the question.